# CSV GUI Import to api -- Set 'Last update date'?

Tags: import, data-import, csv

I'm importing with "CSV GUI Import to api" extension about 6500 contacts. Is it possible to set 'Last update' date during the import from an in the original database existing data field's value? I can't find the proper entity for it.

Thank You.